# Перенос базы данных с PhpMyAdmin 5.6 на 5.1 (#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет, такой вот вопрос. Мне нужно перенести базу данных с одного хоста на другой. На текущем хосте стоит PhpMyAdmin 5.6(5.6) версии, а на хостинге заказчика - 5.1(5.1). Все таблицы в 5.6 с кодировкой utf8mb4_unicode_ci и если ее заимпортить на 5.1, будет ошибка, что не поддерживается данная кодировка, а если изменить вручную - пропадет вся дата.

Вопрос: как мне реализовать перенос? Может изначально как то можно изменить кодировку перед экспортом чтобы можно было без проблем и без потери данных заимпортить? Или же есть еще какие то варианты?

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Может версия MySQL 5.1 / 5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно экспортировать базу данных, открыть ее с помощью редактора и провести несколько манипуляций:
 - заменить `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` на `utf8_general_ci`; 
 - заменить `utf8mb4` на `utf8`; 
Магия, у Вас работает база данных.
Всем спасибо за просмотр!